# DB2 .Net Connector error : AESEncryptADONet

Tags: .net-core, db2, db2-400

I have a very simple .Net Core app trying to create and open a connection to a DB2 database (on AS/400).
I have this error when I try to create the DBConnection object, with the message:

> `ERROR 58005 SQL0902 There are no context policies. Function: AESEncryptADONet`.

There are no more details, unfortunately.

Comment: Whose ODBC driver are you using to access the i-series , and which version? Can you access the same database via using odbcad32 GUI on your workstation?

Comment: I'm not using an ODBC driver, I'm using .Net Core DB2 drivers.

Answer (score 4):

Install the VC++ runtimes (x86 and x64)

You should go with at least the 2013 version as well as the latest. Should solve your problem. It did for me.

I had a fresh 2019 Windows Server, installed dotnet 6 runtime , and I couldn't run my .NET6 applications (Web and console) trying to connect to my DB2 DB using "Net.IBM.Data.Db2": "6.0.0.200", as it threw the same error as you.

I installed the runtimes and it solved the issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

We meet the same error and solved it by setting **`Path`** of environment variables on Windows / Linux (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) / MacOS (`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`).
For example:

1. Our environment:

   - ASP.NET Core v3.1
   - IBM .NET Core 3.1 / EntityFrameworkCore 3.1 in v11.5.4
   - IIS 8.5
   - Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bits)
2. In web.config, we add the `<environmentVariable name="Path" value="C:\Users\Administrator\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core\3.1.0.200\buildTransitive\clidriver\bin" />`.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <location ... >
       <system.webServer>

         ...

         <aspNetCore ... >
           <environmentVariables>
             <environmentVariable name="Path" value="C:\Users\Administrator\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core\3.1.0.200\buildTransitive\clidriver\bin" />
           </environmentVariables>
         </aspNetCore>
       </system.webServer>
     </location>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. Set folder permissions (Read & Execute, Read, and List Folder Contents) for **Application Pool Identity Accounts** (`IIS AppPool\[App_Pool_Name]`)

Please click the links below for more information.

- [Frequently asked questions about IBM Db2 .NET Core Provider](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/blogs/michelle-betbadal1/2020/04/29/frequently-asked-questions-about-ibm-db-net-core-p)

  > Q: I am getting the following error:
  >
  > > An unexpected exception has occurred in  Process: 244 Function: AESEncryptADONET (Encryption Info)
  >
  > The .NET driver is unable to find the compatible GSKit. Set the `Path`(on Windows) or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`(on Linux) to the `<Package_Install_location>/<package-name>/<version>/build/clidriver/lib` directory of your environment. Remember, this may affect other applications.
- [Db2 .NET Packages downloading and initial configuration](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/blogs/vishwa-hs1/2020/07/12/db2-net-packages-download-and-configure)

Answer (score 1):

Putting these lines into my Azure Function App csproj did the trick:

```
<!--For publishing-->
<Target Name="CopyFilesAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Publish">
<Exec Command="(robocopy $(PublishDir)clidriver\ $(PublishDir)bin\clidriver /E) 
^&amp; IF %25ERRORLEVEL%25 LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0" />
</Target>
<!--For debugging-->
<Target Name="CopyFilesAfterBuildToPublish" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
<Exec Command="(robocopy $(TargetDir)clidriver\ $(TargetDir)bin\clidriver /E) 
^&amp; IF %25ERRORLEVEL%25 LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable X64 and X86 - Visual Studio **!!! 2013 !!!** (VC++ 12.0). The newest version (Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022) did not work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, the error encountered on my end was unexpected and somewhat silly. During development, I was using `.NET 6.0` as expected and when I clicked "publish", the IDE used the [also installed on the PC] `.NET 7.0` sdk to bundle the Web API, which caused a conflict in the CLI Driver.

**Conclusion:** Ensure that the **SDK version and dependency version match** both in development and upon publishing.