# Conect Db2 from .ner core 3.1 running on Docker

Tags: linux, docker, db2

### We are trying to connect DB2 from .netcore 3.1 console app and running the code on Docker( linux OS)
We are receiving the following error

There are no context policies. Function: AESEncryptADONET (Encryption Info)
CallStack:    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.HandleUnknownErrors(String strFncMsg, Exception exception, Boolean bThrow)
at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.EncryptString(String value)
at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(DB2Connection connection, String szValue, DB2ConnSettings& pSettings, DB2ConnSettingsInternal& pSettingsInternal, Boolean bAttach, Boolean pushDownStrAppended)
at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)

We have set the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** as
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/clidriver/lib/"

Comment: Check each of the suggestions here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175964/db2-net-connector-error-aesencryptadonet

Comment: Thanks !  we have tried all options given in the link. We are using IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx dll. Also setting all the env variables in the docker file. According to the IBM FAQ, the root cause could be "The .NET driver is unable to find the compatible GSKit". Do we need to install the GSkit also as we are using SSL connection. We are providing the certificate path with the connection string only. Do we need to provide GSkit path also ???

Comment: Enough of the GSKit is already included in current-builds of CLIDRIVER. Most likely a setup issue. Shell into the container, and manually verify clidriver by running its commands like `db2level`  and `db2cli validate` . Look in the Db2 Knowledge centre for details of command-lines.